# Why (System.out.printf() == null) is true in java, Is PrintStream is null?

Tags: java

Why `PrintStream == null` ?

I tried the following code and it worked

```
if (System.out.printf("Som text") == null);
```

As `printf()` returns `PrintStream` then why is it equal to null, Please explain...

Comment: public PrintStream printf(String format, Object ... args) {
        return format(format, args);
    }

Comment: look, It returns PrintStream

Comment: Who says it is equal to `null`? You just test it, but discard the test result.

Comment: What is your proof that it is equal to `null`? Your code doesn't bother to do anything with the result of the comparison. So where is your claim coming from?

Comment: You can also do `System.out.println(System.out.printf(""));` to print the `return` value, and you can see it prints the hashcode.

Comment: sorry sir.......

Comment: Yes you are Right, I am not doing anything with result...

Answer (score 6):

The `PrintStream` isn't `null`.

```
if (System.out.printf("Som text") == null)
{
    System.out.println("True");
}
```

Output:

```
Som text
```

`printf()` returns: This output stream (according to the documentation)

You have to place something inside the `if` statement to check whether `printf()` returns null or not. Otherwise, you will not know since calling `printf()` alone will already print the text `Som text`.